# How to add elements in a 3D array in Swift using for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a 3D array and I initialize it like this ,

```
 var contexts:[[[AnyObject]]] = []
```

and I have two arrays, one is a 2D array contains String values and other one is also a 2D array contains Double values.

```
stringValuesOfData = [["1 GB", "300 MB", "724 MB"], ["10 GB", "0 MB", "10 GB"]] 
byteValuesOfData = [[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0],[10737418240.0, 0.0, 10737418240.0]]
```

Now I want to add these two array elements into contexts array like this

```
contexts =[[["1 GB", "300 MB", "724 MB"],[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0]], [[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0],[10737418240.0, 0.0, 10737418240.0]]]
```

How can I do this?.

I tried like this and It gave me error

```
for i in 0..<self.stringValuesOfData.count {
 contexts[i] = [[stringValuesOfData[i],byteValuesOfData[i]]]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `contexts[i]` you are trying to access object of contexts which does not exist so instead of doing that append new data:

```
    for i in 0..<stringValuesOfData.count {
        contexts.append([[stringValuesOfData[i],byteValuesOfData[i]]])
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working but I think one square bracket should be removed to get answer `contexts =[[["1 GB", "300 MB", "724 MB"],[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0]], [[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0],[10737418240.0, 0.0, 10737418240.0]]]`

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a type cast issue.

```
var contexts:[[[AnyObject]]] = []


let stringValuesOfData:[[AnyObject]] = [["1 GB", "300 MB", "724 MB"], ["10 GB", "0 MB", "10 GB"]]
let byteValuesOfData:[[AnyObject]] = [[1073741824.0, 314572800.0, 759169024.0],[10737418240.0, 0.0, 10737418240.0]]

for i in stringValuesOfData.indices {
    contexts.append([ stringValuesOfData[i], byteValuesOfData[i] ])    
}
```

On a playground, this gives:

[image: contexts]